# Google Playstore app still in review from last 7 days. Can anyone help me for that?

Tags: android, upload, release

[image]**Google play store app in review from last 7 days**

I've uploaded my app on the google play store, I had uploaded one app for testing and one for production. I don't know what is the issue. Can anyone face the same issue than please let me know.
Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bro no one can help in this matter. Usually the app is under review for 3-4-5 days. A similar incident happened with me, in my case there was something that was violating the policy. In this case Google Play took around 1 month for review and after that they rejected the publish request and notified that some policies are being violated and suggested to update the app according to the policies.

**Answer :**  Wait and watch, that's the only thing you can do for now I believe.

Comment: @Bhavesh Makwana Kindly up vote the answer as it may help someone in future.